# Is Build.ID unique?

Tags: android, build, unique, android-11

Is Build.ID unique?
If it is, can it still be used in android 11?

`Build.ID`

if not, what unique identifier can I use to differentiate devices?(one that doesn't require any permission or anything like logins or emails)

Comment: Google's recommendations for IDs are here:  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: But as for Build.ID-  that doesn't identify a device.  It identifies the build of the Android OS from the OEM.  It will be the same across a wide range of devices (all devices of the same model most likely).

Comment: aight, thanks Gabe